# what does the three dots in this python line of code mean?

Tags: python

I found this line of python code online -

```
table = {'Sjoerd': 4127, 'Jack': 4098, 'Dcab': 8637678}
>>> print('Jack: {0[Jack]:d}; Sjoerd: {0[Sjoerd]:d}; '
...       'Dcab: {0[Dcab]:d}'.format(table))
```

And this executes perfectly to give me - **Jack: 4098; Sjoerd: 4127; Dcab: 8637678**

But when I tried removing the three dots and running the code I got an error

```
table = {'Sjoerd': 4127, 'Jack': 4098, 'Dcab': 8637678}
>>> print('Jack: {0[Jack]:d}; Sjoerd: {0[Sjoerd]:d}; Dcab: {0[Dcab]:d}'.format(table))
```

Error -

```
File "<ipython-input-53-2065564231a1>", line 3
    >>> print('Jack: {0[Jack]:d}; Sjoerd: {0[Sjoerd]:d}; Dcab: {0[Dcab]:d}'.format(table))
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this happening? what does the three dots in the 1st code mean?
I'm new to python/programming so apologies if this seemed like a simple question.

thanks

Comment: It's the continuation of a line indicator when using ipython etc;

Comment: It's not part of the code, just as the `>>>` isn't part of the code.

Comment: but why didn't the code work when I removed the dots and moved it to a single line

Comment: This probably indicates the indentation when you execute python from command prompt. Plz look into this https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: I think the syntax error is indicating the `>>>`?! Because that's not part of the code. The `...` are irrelevant. The problem is that you're trying to execute code including the `>>>`.

Comment: Wherever you found this code was probably just trying to illustrate with a sample from the interactive Python interpreter.

Comment: Yes! thanks. I removed the >>> and it worked in a single line.
but why did it run in the first case where >>> and ... was present in the code.
I'm using jupyter notebooks to run this btw

Comment: Did it really work?! It's enclosed in `'''`, so it shouldn't be doing anything.

Comment: sorry my bad. I'm new to stackoverflow as well so ended up using the ''' for the code. It's not there in the actual code

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode):

*When commands are read from a `tty`, the interpreter is said to be in **interactive mode**.*

In this mode it prompts for the next command with the primary prompt, usually three greater-than signs (`>>>`); for continuation lines it prompts with the secondary prompt, by default three dots (`...`).

The interpreter prints a welcome message stating its version number and a copyright notice before printing the first prompt

Answer (score 0):

The code works when you remove the >>> from it. the >>> was giving the error.

The code also works if you use >>> in the first line and ... in the next line.
Jupyter notebooks was used to run this code.